# How can I easily find the public LAN address of a Virtual Box VM in a public environment?

Tags: virtualbox, ip, arch-linux

I’m using VirtualBox on Arch Linux and I’m learning some hacking stuff using OVA’s from VulnHub, imported into VirtualBox. Most times I generate a hackable webserver with an IP address, which I can reach over the network in bridged mode.

On my home network I can find the OVA easily by scanning my home network with nmap or netdiscover. Then I have the IP 192.168.xxx.xxx. to reach the webserver over the browser - no problem.

But now, I’m in my university and want to demonstrate some OVA’s, but I dont know the IP address of the VM, so I can”t reach the webserver. I'm running VirtualBox in bridged mode, too, so my VirtualBox is on the same network as me.

I know, I could scan the whole university network, but that”s not very performant and smart and the server admin wouldn't be amused, I think. 
Is there another way, of getting my IP address of the VirtualBox (OVA), instead of scanning with nmap or netdiscover?

I found some answers that recommend using the Virtualbox Manager but it’s not available for Arch Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You are learning about hacking stuff and you don't know how to solve this? I find that VERY hard to believe.

Log in to the VM. Even a pre-configured OVA will have a way to login. Check the documentation for that OVA image.

When you are in the command `ifconfig -a` will tell you all you need to know.

Some other Linux distro's use the command `ip addr show` for that.

(Most Linux based VM's will actually display a banner showing their IP-address on the login-screen as well.)

Comment: goal is to get the login data. i cant login to type ifconfig in the vm......

Comment: this would be the easy way i figured out before...sure..but this is not what i asked for

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so as sometimes happens when you ask a question, you usually come up with the answer yourself ...

With the command  `VBoxManage list bridgedifs`  you can see the VM's that are in bridged mode.

`VBoxManage` is probably already installed by default under virtualbox ...

Now I know the IP, but still can not access the web server - that seems to be another problem, maybe the admin does not allow it at the college to host a web-server - which would make sense anyway.

thanks anyway to everyone
regards

Comment: I recommend *not* using bridged mode, but instead keeping the VM local to your host. You can still demonstrate everything with that setup. If I was IT staff at your university, you'd get a very stern talking to for letting random VM images where you don't know what stuff it does access the internal university network (which is hopefully secured, but still.)... And keeping the VM local will also rule out any "I can't access the webserver on the VM because the university doesn't allow it".